# Handling a ReadTimeoutException with Spring's WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webclient

I'm making a call to a REST service using the Spring WebClient, and I am trying to handle an `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException` which might happen from time to time:

```
            try {
                List<Asset> assets = client.searchAssets("some-type", assetCode);
                // do sometihng
            } catch (ReadTimeoutException ex) {
                log.error("TimeoutException, can't wait no more :)");
            }
```

However, when there is a Timeout Exception, this seems to be the exception I'm getting: `WebClientRequestException`

My question is, should I catch this `WebClientRequestException` instead? How will I ever know if this was due to a `ReadTimeoutException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring's WebClient, exceptions from the underlying netty library (like `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException`) are often wrapped in a `WebClientRequestException`. This is why you're seeing the `WebClientRequestException` instead of the `TimeoutException`.

When you catch a WebClientRequestException, you can check its cause to see if it is a TimeoutException. Here's an example of how to do that:

```java
try {
    // do something
} catch (WebClientRequestException ex) {
    if (ex.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException) {
        // timeout
    } else {
        // else
    }
}
```

Please be aware that the timeout exception you may encounter is not the standard `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` but rather the `io.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException`. It's important to note that handling this exception will create a dependency (coupling) on the Netty library. If you modify the Spring WebClient configuration and switch the underlying library from Netty to another option, you must also update your code accordingly.